# iOS can I programmatically present UITableViewRowAction, or have it stay visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, uitableviewrowaction

I have a side swipe menu implemented for a `UITableView` using `UITableViewRowAction`. I would like to add a "Done" button to this menu and have it visible while the user is editing a cell. Once "Done" is pressed, the action would complete normally.

**Can I programmatically present `UITableViewRowAction` for a specific table view row?**

or

**Can I have `UITableViewRowAction` stay visible after user taps one of its buttons?**

Comment: How did you solve this ?